# What does "get between Abbie and a camera" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Chicago 7 group was represented by prosecutor William:

> William: I don't want you guys holding any more press conferences.
>
> Tom: If you're gonna **get between Abbie and a camera**, I'd wear pads and
> a  helmet.

What does "get between Abbie and a camera" mean? Is Tom suggesting William not
to advice Abbie about press conference?

Source: The Trial of the Chicago 7 (2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"get between (someone) and (something)" is a phrase that in this context means stop someone from using something. It is almost always used in the context of advising someone not to stop someone doing something.

For example, "Don't get between John and cake" would mean don't try to stop John from eating cake.

In this case, William is saying they shouldn't have press conferences. Abbie loves publicity and this would be hindered by the termination of the press conferences. Tom is saying to William that stopping Abbie from "using" the camera (In this case, he will be filmed by the camera to be in the press conferences) is a mistake. And that, if he must do it, he will need pads and a helmet for protection from Abbie who will try to get to the camera by any means necessary. (This last part may be exaggeration for emphasis or it may be a legitimate warning)

Comment: Good answer in general but "Abbie" is "Abbie Hoffman", a leader of the Chicago 7, who, apparently loved publicity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Seven

Comment: Also, the suggestion isn't that Abbie will be angry, but that given his inclinations, he will get to the camera one way or the other, so don't get in the way without protective gear.

Comment: To be clear, Abbie Hoffman (Abbot Howard Hoffman, 1936-1989) was a man.

Comment: I believe the intended meaning is that Hoffman would hate anyone getting in the way of a press or other photographer taking a photograph of him, or a TV news camera.

Comment: "A camera" suggests any random camera, not a camera belonging to Hoffman.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - a "good answer" except it is wrong about the meaning and thinks Abbie Hoffman was a woman.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I don't think it has anything to do with hate. It has to do with the physical hazard of being in the path of someone who wants something a lot. "Pads and a helmet" don't suggest hate, but a joking warning to stay out of the way.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. I have updated the answer to reflect these points

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - parse "hate anyone getting" as "hate or strongly dislike the fact of someone getting in the way", not "hate the person getting in the way".

Comment: @ededededed87 - Hoffman is not wanting to get to the camera or "use" it. He just doesn't want the view of himself blocked that any camera operated by anyone might have.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I disagree. There's no dislike involved. It's a joke. If you get between him and the publicity he loves, put on armor - he'll bowl you over.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That doesn't seem right based on the first sentence with William saying not to have any press conferences.

Comment: Decreeing no press conferences would, in effect, "get between Abbie and a camera", since it would reduce the opportunities for him to have his picture in newspapers and magazines or on TV.

Comment: Yes. That's what I have said in my answer